# Update etcd and root volume to gp3 with enabled encryption

Tags: kops

KOPS v1.20.0 will start creating new clusters with `gp3` type and volume encryption enabled for ETCD and root volumes.

We have an existing cluster running and I wonder which of the operations are permitted for a running cluster. From what I saw one can change volume type and enable encryption of root volumes but not of etcd volumes. Does that also apply to upgrade from etcd volume `gp2` to `gp3`?

Is there any way to enable encryption of etcd volumes of an existing cluster?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just read a thread in Kubernetes/kops-dev slack channel where someone upgraded the node `rootVolumeType` volume type from `gp2` to `gp3` successfully but ran into IOPS/VolumeSize issues when changing the volume type for ETCD. You have to tune the parameters correctly to make it work. If all settings line up, you should be able to change the volume type.

Comment: Actually, not sure if intentionally or a bug in `kops` itself, but after upgrading `kops` to v1.20 and running cluster update with it, `etcd` volumes have been automatically changed to `gp3`

Comment: It is the default now so makes sense.